# Having issues with Putty

Tags: networking, server, ssh

First, I want to say that I have decided to make the switch completely to be a Linux user now. So what I am about to say very much well could be a user error issue.

I have installed PuTTY onto Ubuntu and the menu pulls up just fine. What I am trying to do is connect to my Oracle Virtual Machine, in this case I am trying to connect to the Kali Linux OS I have installed. Once I enter the IP address in the PuTTY menu, it closes out the application. Literally kills itself, and I am not sure why. I started to do some experimenting with other IP addresses and server names and websites, with the same result. Not sure what gives but could use some help or better yet an alternative to PuTTY hoping for that SSH Application to work.

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system and version is the **host** of the virtual system? What operating system and version is the **guest** of the virtual system? -- We know about Ubuntu and Ubuntu family flavours here, but we don't know about Kali Linux. So we can only help you 'on the Ubuntu side'. Which of the operating systems is the SSH server? Kali? If problems there, you must find help elsewhere.

Comment: Gotcha! Well that's helpful I am using Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: OK, Is Ubuntu 21.10 host or guest of the virtual system? And which system is SSH server? Is there also some other operating system? Is the server in the same computer or in another computer in a local network?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 is the Host. I have installed Virtual Machine and PuTTY on Ubuntu only. Kali is my guest machine.

Comment: That is good to know. So Kali is guest in the Ubuntu machine. Do you want to connect between them via SSH? Have you installed an SSH server into Ubuntu or Kali?

Comment: Yes Correct Kali is guest in my Ubuntu machine. Yes I found my Kali IP and was trying to type it in Putty. Yes I just double check the status on Ubuntu and it's been active, and Kali SSH status is active after running the "sudo service ssh status" command.

Comment: So you have an SSH server running in Kali, and you have a network address in the local network (via your router)? Then I suggest that you try to log in via Ubuntu's own terminal window (gnome-terminal) with the command line `ssh user-name@ip-address` (a user-name and IP-address at Kali).

Comment: If problems, try with `-v` or `-vv` or `-vvv` for increased verbosity to see error messages, `ssh -v ...`

Comment: ssh: connect to host IP-address port 22: Connection timed out this is what I got in my Ubuntu Terminal.

Comment: What is the network setting in the VirtualBox machine? I suggest that you set **bridged** network (I think the default is NAT, and it does not get in contact via the router of the local network.)

Comment: I think I am getting somewhere now. I went ahead and changed my network to bridged and attempted the SSH user@IP command again however this time it's telling me that the connection was refused.

Comment: It seems to work on the Ubuntu side including VirtualBox. I think Kali is refusing the connection. Maybe there is a firewall, where you can modify a setting. But it is outside my competence to trouble-shoot Kali. If you want to learn networking with SSH, it is better to have the SSH server in a more user-friendly Linux distro (for example Ubuntu).

Comment: Maybe Kali's ssh server is set to only accept key authentication (and not password). You can find general instructions for that (should not be specific for Kali).

Comment: Hey I actually got it up and running now! Thank you for you're help

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 and ran into the same problem , this is the work around I found.

as root uninstall putty by running `apt remove putty-tools`

then reinstall using `apt install putty putty-tools -y`

once installed launch putty as root from terminal with `putty`